# How to add a function to every key in array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I am using code igniter and I have an array which stores data sent from the form.
Sometimes user can type a text with a space, ex " John", or "James ", so I would like to use a trim() function to delete those whitespaces.

```
$data = array(
    'name'          => ' James',
    'surname'       => 'Doe  ',
    'street_name'   => ' The Steet',
    'number'        => '45 flat 5/6 ',
    'postcode'      => ' 12-345 ',
    'city'          => ' New York ',
    );
```

Instead of adding a trim to every single line in array I would prefer to add a function which will go key by key and use a trim function to every key in array. How to do that?

Comment: have a look at `array_map`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

Comment: Codeigniter has a build in formbuilder an validation. Trim is a part of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) function applies a function to every element in an array. In this case, the function you want is [`trim`](http://php.net/trim).

```
$trimmedData = array_map('trim', $data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest vanilla code to understand the process

```
foreach($data as $key=>$val) {
  $data[$key] = trim($val);
}
var_dump($data);
```

or use a function e.g. array_map()

Answer (score 1):

```
$newarray = array_map("trim", $old_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

A function?

```
function trim_whitespace_from_array( $input ){
    foreach($input as $key=>$val) {
      $input[$key] = trim($val);
    }
    return $input;
}

$data = array(
'name'          => ' James',
'surname'       => 'Doe  ',
'street_name'   => ' The Steet',
'number'        => '45 flat 5/6 ',
'postcode'      => ' 12-345 ',
'city'          => ' New York ',
);

$trimmed = trim_whitespace_from_array($data);
```

Pretty much the same as what @donald123 said.

Comment: Thank you - this works fine, but in my case the trim() function do the job.

Comment: Yeah, the answer marked as correct is certainly the best answer here.

Answer (score 1):

The function you want already exists. It's called [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php). It allows one to call a custom function (that would be `trim()` in your case) on all the values from an array and produces an array from the values returned by that function; it preserves the keys.

```
$data = array_map('trim', $data);
```